# CSS UL as table with float left

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

At some point my code is not working for multi lines table with ul. Everything is on link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/eagerwolf/GXxLn/

I added

```
width: 300px;
```

to parent element. In real this is limited with div... but never mind issue stays the same...

Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this with a <ul> and not with a <table>?

Comment: I was just wondering if it is possible to do that using ul...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are using a cricket bat to play baseball

*Use `table` for tabular layouts*

Change your markup, use `table`, `tr`, `td` and not <s>`ul`</s>, `ul` are meant for listing items.

---

If anyways you want to use `ul` and `li` for creating a table layout, than you should use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` which changes the `display` of the elements, but still, you shouldn't do that, you will find hard to use `display: table-row;` and such properties as only `li` can be nested as a direct child to `ul` element.

Comment: OK I understand ... this is than not possible. Thanks for suggests!

Comment: @M.V. the question is not about possibility, ofcourse it's possible, but your approach is not correct

Comment: With some testing I found out this is not reliable solution ... As you have mentioned in edit... problem occurs with nesting...

Comment: @M.V. yes it does, prefer `<table>` for this, with `rowspan` and `colspan`